# how to ensure that JDialog always stays on top

Tags: java, visibility, jdialog

I have a `JDialog` that takes a name from the user. Behind the `JDialog`, is an applet. I dont want the user to access that applet until he has entered the name. I tried `JDialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true)`, but the applet throws an `AccessException` error. So what I did was keep a while loop that will execute `JDialog.setVisible(true)` till the `JtextField`(input for user name) is empty (""). But for some reason this works really slow, meaning the `JDialog`  loads, but it takes time to focus on the `JTextField` and even when the user types his name, it comes really slow... like one character in 2 seconds... Is there any other way for me to force the user to enter the name before accessing the applet?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a modal JDialog. For example the code in your init(...) method of JApplet might include:

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(this));
dialog.setModal(true);
dialog.setSize(...);
dialog.setVisible( true );
```

Or you can just use a JOptionPane.showInputDialog(). Again you would just specify "this" as the parent component of the option pane.

Comment: But theres one problem. ActionListeners are no longer responding. And also, the user can close the dialog (there is an x at the top right of the dialog). Is there anything I need to restore after the user has entered the name?

Comment: If you don't want the user to be able to close the dialog then use: dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(...);

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be:

```
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

It forces the dialog on top of any other.

Answer (score 0):

It runs slowly because the program is processing that foo loop

What you can do is to add a window listener and then the jdialog lost it's focus ( or the applet gains it ) return the focus to the jdialog.

This should perform much better than the for loop you're using right now

Comment: If ModalityTypes work for applets, I would suggest that instead. I don't have time to find out, though.

Comment: I added a FocusListener to JDialog and wrote the body for the focusLost() function in it. However, it doesnt seem to work. If the user clicks outide the JDialog, it doesn't display again. I think clicking outside the JDialog doesn't cause the JDialog to lose focus, it just gets hidden.